# How to restrict Spartacus Authentication to certain customers?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm new to Spartacus storefront development but have worked in Hybris/SAP Commerce for some years,

Setting up spartacus I noticed that in the AuthenticationService, customers can log in over the REST API from any base store. The call simply goes to hybris with user e-mail/id and password, and is then authenticated to the store.

Is there possibility to restrict only users from one basestore to that specific spartacus storefront? Or groups on said user. Just something to not expose the spartacus storefront to all Customers...

Thank you

Comment: Hey @arthurjs! We have the same requirement as you described above. Have you solved the problem somehow?

Comment: @ArtemZur I posted an answer to what we did

Answer (score 1):

We made a `RequiredRoleMatchingFilter extends AbstractUrlMatchingFilter`
that checks a custom role attribute (`UserGroupModel`) on `BaseSite` level

So something like this

```java
private static final String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";
private BaseSiteService baseSiteService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                                    final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final Authentication auth = getAuth();
        boolean isCustomer = false;
        if (hasRole(ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP, auth) || hasRole(ROLE_CUSTOMERMANAGERGROUP, auth)) {
            isCustomer = true;
        }

        final Optional<BaseSiteModel> currentBaseSite = Optional.ofNullable(getBaseSiteService().getCurrentBaseSite());
        if (isCustomer && currentBaseSite.isPresent() && currentBaseSite.get().getRequiredRole() != null) {
            final UserGroupModel requiredRole = currentBaseSite.get().getRequiredRole();
            final String REQUIRED_ROLE = ROLE_PREFIX + requiredRole.getUid().toUpperCase();
            if (hasRole(REQUIRED_ROLE, auth)) {
                LOG.debug("Authorized as " + requiredRole.getUid());
            } else {
                // could not match the authorized role
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Access is denied");
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Hey @arthurjs! How did you manage that '/authorizationserver/oauth/token' doesn't contain 'basesiteid', how do you know from which 'basesite' a user wants to authorize? Did you also customize the authorization service?

Comment: Uh, when the user is logging in on our spartacus store/store, this can get resolved:
getBaseSiteService().getCurrentBaseSite()

So this role filter seems to work fine in our case. If you want to block it on the authorizationserver side of things (so even before calling the log-in API) I'm not sure how you should do it.

Comment: I just double-checked the solution with our backend team, it works for us as well. And customization of the '/authorizationserver/oauth/token' service with such filter is not needed. Thank you!

Comment: All right, awesome ;)